# What is the best practice in React Navigation to update a list of items after the item is altered?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Here is the scenario :
I have a bottom tab with two tabs : Actions and People
One Action always belong to one Person
On the People tab, I can view, add and edit an Action to do

If I am in the stack People > Person from where I edit an action,
How can I update only the Action row in the Actions list ? What is the best practice ?

The best would be to not use redux for this if possible, in order to make a good use of react navigation's redux...

Tell me if it's not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

It might help to see some example code, but generally speaking you want to move the information from the "Person" screen all the way up to a common parent and then back down to a child (the Action screen/tab).

Here's some pseudo code with only 1 action, where changing the action on a Person Screen will ultimately update that action in the Action Tab:

```
function Root({  }) {

const [action, setAction] = useState('initialAction')

  return (
    <View >

      <PeopleTab setAction={setAction} action={action} />
      <ActionTab setAction={setAction} action={action}  />
    
    </View>
  );
}



function PeopleTab({ setAction, action  }) {

  return (
    <View >
      <PersonScreen setAction={setAction} action={action}/>
    </View>
  );
}

function PersonScreen({ setAction, action  }) {

  return (
    <View >

// handle setting the action here with some onPress={() => setAction('new action'))
    
    </View>
  );
}

function ActionTab({ setAction, action  }) {

  return (
    <View >

// Handle displaying the action here {action}
    
    </View>
  );
}
```